# Django model form save() method not creating profile object

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

Consider following code:

```
class CandidateSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Ime', 'class': 'validate'}))
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Prezime'), 'class': 'validate'}))

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    widgets = {
        'email': forms.EmailInput(
            attrs = {
                'placeholder': _('E-mail'),
                'class': 'validate'
            },
        ),

        'password': forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs = {
                'placeholder': _('Lozinka'),
                'class': 'validate'
            },
        ),

    }

def signup(self, user):
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    user.password = self.cleaned_data['password']

    user.save()

    candidate = Candidate()
    candidate.user = user
    candidate.save()
```

and my models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_candidate = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_employer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

    mobile =  models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Candidate(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True
    )

    available_from = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    dob = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank = True, null=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank = True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + ' ' + self.user.last_name
```

Now, given I'm using Django AllAuth, I needed to override `signup` method, to be able to save `User` object. Using said code, my User is saved properly, while Candidate is not saved at all, ie, no records in candidate table.

I've tried literally everything, but still can't figure out what may have gone wrong.

UPDATE:

changing `candidate.user = user` to `candidate.user = user.pk`, doesn't make it work, either.

Comment: Try this `candidate.user = user.pk` Also, is there any exception?

Comment: @shafik nope, that doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your method is being called. First you need to change the method from `def signup(self, request)` to `def signup(self, request, user)`:

```
class CandidateSignUpForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(...)
    last_name = forms.CharField(...)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        candidate = Candidate()
        candidate.user = user
        candidate.save()
```

Then point that From from settings like this:

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'PATH.TO.CandidateSignUpForm'
```

Details regarding this override can be found [here](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to link the Candidate-Model with with the ID of your User-Model? 
So, for your case something like this:

```
user = user.save()
candidate = Candidate.objects.create(user_id=user.id)
```